# change data columns into JSON with different roots in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

in SQL Server, I have to change the data columns format into a JSON with different roots format, but I do not know how I should wrote.

Input:

| PersonCode | Name | Realation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 961113026 | Sara Smite | Wife |

Output:

```
 [{"Name":{"DataType":"string","value":"Sara Smite"},"Relation":{"DataType":"string","value":"Wife"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I should do.It might help you guys:

```
SELECT 'string' AS 'Name.DataType'
  ,Name AS 'Name.value'
  ,'string' AS 'Relation.DataType'
  ,Relation AS 'Relation.value'   
FROM [dbo].[Person]
FOR JSON PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES** and **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS** tables to get the data type.

```
SELECT c.DATA_TYPE as 'Name.DATA_TYPE',p.Name as 'Name.value',
       c.DATA_TYPE as 'Relation.DATA_TYPE',p.Relation as 'Relation.value'
FROM Person p join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on  t.TABLE_NAME = 'Person'
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY c.COLUMN_NAME,c.DATA_TYPE,p.Name,p.
FOR JSON PATH
```